# Robust and automatable droplet fitting

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, geometry, scikit-image

I'm trying to perform image analysis on a set of grayscale images like the following image:

[image: typical image]

The main goal is to be able to measure the dimensions of the elliptical droplets and to identify their center coordinates.
I've tried Hough Circular Transform in openCV and scikit-image. All the examples I've seen so far for scikit-images run quite slowly compared to openCV.

I've had moderate success with this code (taken from the example):

```
img = read_img[600:,:]
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,30,
            param1=45,param2=20,minRadius=1,maxRadius=45)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

cv2.imshow('detected circles',cimg)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=1, figsize=(20, 20))
ax.imshow(cimg)
```

which detects the main droplets, but fails to catch the three smaller ones.

The best threshold I was able to construct is with these parameters for openCV

```
th2 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,\cv2.THRESH_BINARY,15,5)
```

however, I'm still unable to find the smaller droplets using the code above.

I have a couple thousand images that I would want to process. I would need the algorithm to be able to automatically find the optimal parameters for the transforms or thresholding. So far I have no idea how to implement something like this.

Any suggestions for proper implementation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: where exactly is the third small droplet?

Comment: there's a series of 3 satelite droplets above the fourth large cicle from the left

Comment: I noticed after performing adaptive threshold. See the answer below if it helps.

Comment: Try [SimpleBlobDetector](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d0/d7a/classcv_1_1SimpleBlobDetector.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have only suggested a possible pre-processing step not a complete solution. You can perform [adaptive thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) on the green channel of the image.

**Code:**

```
img = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Jackson/Desktop/droplet.jpg', 1)

#--- Resized the image to half of its original dimension --
img = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx = 0.5, fy = 0.5)

#--- I narrowed down to these values after some rigorous trial-and-error ---
th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img[:,:,1], 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 63, 5)

cv2.namedWindow('Original', 0)
cv2.imshow('Original', img) 
cv2.namedWindow('th3', 0)
cv2.imshow('th3', th3)         
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Result:**

[image]

You can carry on from here.